# Accessing an old project from the google code archive

Tags: json, svn, archive, google-code

I realised I needed some data that I parked at Google Code a long time ago, but can't figure out how to fetch it from archive.

<https://archive.ph/wip/Q68GB>  gets me the project overview and tells me hasSource=true and it's in svn. but

> https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive/v2/code.google.com/sm-noaa/source-page-1.json

is not returning any data.

Has anyone figured this one out yet?

Million thanks and eternal glory awaits

Comment: For those with the same question: since the official google address was not replying I reached out to some google engineers. They told me vast amounts of data were never transferred and got lost.

Comment: You can get the whole project dump with full revision history, is that what you want? I'll post an answer if yes.

Comment: Please do! that would make me and possibly others very happy.

Comment: Guide: https://cdominikdorn.com/2016/05/how-to-recover-a-google-code-svn-project-and-migrate-to-github/ Hmm, the method that worked for me for the projects that are available at https://code.google.com/archive/p/ doesn't work here. My projects have pages at https://code.google.com/archive/p/dummyname/source/default/source and https://code.google.com/archive/p/dummyname/source/default/commits, yours doesn't, even though it is there itself. Probably the actual data got taken down. There's this thing though, dunno if it could help you: http://archiveteam.org/index.php?title=Google_Code.

Comment: @CocoaChris What do you mean it "got lost"?